# Recorrer array php muestra la informacion mal

Tags: php, array, table

tengo un array el cual estoy intentando recorrer y me muestra mal la inforamcion o no me muestra nada:

Acudo a su ayuda ya que no encuentro error en mi codigo o bien como podria mejorarlo.

Vista:

```
                            <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($mi_array as $ArrayNovedades) : ?>
                                <?php
                                switch ($ArrayNovedades["Tipo"]) {
                                    case 'A':
                                        $tipo_mov = _('Alta');
                                        break;
                                    case 'B':
                                        $tipo_mov = _('Baja');
                                        break;
                                    case 'M':
                                        $tipo_mov = _('Modificación');
                                        break;
                                }
                                ?>
                                <tr>

                                    <td> <?php echo $ArrayNovedades[0]; ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $tipo_mov; ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo $ArrayNovedades["Novedad"]; ?></td>

                                    <td> <?php echo  $ArrayNovedades["Denuncia"] ? $mi_array["Denuncia"] : "---"; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $ArrayNovedades["Usuario"]; ?></td>
                                    <td> <?php echo  $ArrayNovedades["Lote"]; ?></td>


                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
```

Este es el array del action:

```
            $this->mi_array = array("Fecha" => $devolucion2, 
                                "Tipo" => $devolucion3, 
                                "Novedad" => $devolucion4, 
                                "Denuncia" => $devolucion5, 
                                "Usuario" => $devolucion6, 
                                "Lote" => $devolucion7);
```

Cual podria ser mi error ya que no logro solucionarlo.

Comment: El error es que recorres un array tipo `elemento => valor` como si se tratara de uno `[ [campo1 => valor1, ...campon => valorn], [campo1 => valor1, ...campon => valorn] ]`

Comment: Bien, y como podria recorrer todos los valores ?

Comment: Si continúas con ese array de solo un registro, entonces no necesitas ciclo, quita el foreach y listo.

Comment: El tema es que necesitp recorrer un array y que me devuelva todos los valores, porque hay mas de un valor osea por ejemplo "nombre" => $nombre; hay 10 nombres distintos, como podria recorrer todo eso.

Comment: De acuerdo, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código donde armas el array, porque desde ahí viene el error.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, gracias.